# Angular Acceleration v. Centripetal Acceleration

Tags: acceleration, rotational-kinematics, centripetal-force

What is the difference between angular acceleration and centripetal acceleration? Don't they both apply to circular motion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

angular acceleration:$\frac {d\omega} {dt}$ the change of angular velocity with respect to time

centripetal acceleration: $\omega^2r$ if the orbital is circular.  The component of linear acceleration of a object that causes it to have a angular motion.

Comment: $\omega^2r$ only applies for circular motion. In general centripetal acceleration also has a $\ddot r$ term.

Comment: @Aaron fixed. By the way, is there an elementary expression for the centripetal acceleration in elliptical orbital? Is there a general expression for orbital $r=r(\theta)$?

Comment: For an ellipse $$r(\theta)=\frac{a(1-e^2)}{1+e\cos\theta}$$ where $e$ is the eccentricity and $a$ is the length of the semi-major axis. More info can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit)

Answer (score 1):

Angular acceleration $\vec{\alpha}$ is defined as $$\vec{\alpha}=\frac{d\vec{\omega}}{dt}$$

$\vec{\omega}$ is the angular acceleration of the particle.

Centripetal acceleration in circular motion is given as

$$\vec{a}=-\omega^2r\vec{e_{r}}$$

$\vec{e_{r}}$ is the unit vector along radial direction.

Answer (score 1):

In general, angular acceleration ($\vec a$) is the rate of change of angular velocity $\vec \omega$ w.r.t. time i.e. $$\vec a=\frac{d\vec \omega}{dt}$$
An object in curvi-linear (non-circular) motion can have angular acceleration

While the centripetal acceleration causes a body to rotate in a circular path & its magnitude is $$a_c=r\omega^2$$
Arc length traversed by the body with tangential velocity $v$ in time $dt$ on a circular path of radius $r$ is given as
$$rd\theta=vdt$$$$ \frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{v}{r}$$ 
$$\omega=\frac{v}{r}$$
$$v=r\omega$$
In circular motion, the differential change in tangential velocity: $$dv=vd\theta$$ 
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=v\frac{d\theta}{dt}$$
$$a_c=r\omega\cdot \omega$$
$$a_c=r\omega^2$$

In vector form $$\color{blue}{\vec{a_c}=- r\omega^2\hat{r}}$$
Where $\hat{r}$ is unit radial vector.